# Lazy data loading with rich:dataTable and rich:dataTableScroller

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am using `rich:dataTable` with `rich:dataTableScroller`. And I don't want load all my data from DB when initialize table, because I have very many records. I want that that `rich:dataTableScroller` show me real page count but load page only when I switch on in. I find some solution [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/10/effective-datatable-paging-and-sorting.html)
But I want use `rich:dataTable` and`rich:dataTableScroller`, and don't write my own components. Have somebody some ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a custom `org.richfaces.model.DataProvider`, and in `getItemsByRange` you should fetch the limited data. 
You should then construct an `ExtendedTableDataModel` passing your custom `DataProvider`, and use this model in your `<rich:dataTable>` - `value="#{myBean.myExtendedDataModel}"`

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own "PagedDataModel", which actually returns only the data that will be shown in the page you are seeing.

I have found an example for this [here](http://facestutorials.icefaces.org/tutorial/dataTable-JPA-tutorial.html#page).

Answer (score -1):

You can write your own datamodel as child of richfaces ExtendedDataModel, which has method:

`protected List<T> loadData(int offset, int limit, List<Order> orders)`

Comment: He meant that "your own" datamodel should have this method. Similar as `ScrollableTableDataModel` has.

Comment: and if he just defines that method, and noone calls it, it would be useless. Furthermore, the last argument in `ScrollableTableDataModel` is the SortOrder, not a list